# A way to prove that the partial derivatives are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow M$ be a chart on the manifold $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$.

I want to show that the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}|_{x_{0}}$
  are linearly independent, *i.e.* $$\underset{i=1}{\overset{m}{\sum}}c_{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}|_{x_{0}}=0_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}=:0\ \mbox{ iff }\ \forall i\in\{1,...,n\},\,c_{i}=0$$

But this can be translated into an equation in the matrix vector space $M_{n\times1}(\mathbb{R})$
 , isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$
 . The matrix corresponding to the $i^{th}$
  partial derivative is $$Jf|_{x_{0}}\cdot\mathbb{E}_{i}=Jf|_{x_{0}}\cdot\underset{\in M_{m\times1}(\mathbb{R})}{\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{c}
0\\
\vdots\\
1\\
\vdots\\
0
\end{array}\right]}}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{i}}|_{x_{0}}\\
\vdots\\
\frac{\partial f_{n}}{\partial x_{i}}|_{x_{0}}
\end{array}\right]$$

How can I show that these vectors are linearly independent?

Comment: Your vectors on the right hand side are just the columns of $df$ (which you are calling $Jf$). Since $f$ is a chart map, it is by definition a diffeomorphism. The differential of a diffeomorphism is injective, so the columns of this matrix are linearly independent.

Comment: @Nick Just to confirm: you say that the derivative of a diffeomorphism is injective because the derivative is easily seen to be invertible and hence bijective, right? But then I thought the argument would be that the derivative is surjective, so the rank of the jacobian matrix would be maximal, which is equivalent to the columns spanning the whole codomain...

Comment: Right. Essentially the inverse function theorem.

Comment: @Nick I added this and you probably did not see it, sorry: But then I thought the argument would be that the derivative is surjective, so the rank of the jacobian matrix would be maximal, which is equivalent to the columns spanning the whole codomain..

Comment: Either argument is probably fine. For finite-dimensional vector spaces, an endomorphism is injective if and only if it is surjective.

Comment: Yes, but this is not an endomorphism. But it seems you argument is fine because, by the rank-nullity theorem, if the kernel has dimension zero, then $rank(J)=\text{total number of columns of }J=m$, so they are linearly independent.

Comment: @Nick I think $Df(x_0)$ cannot be bijective: it would be an isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$

Comment: No, it would not be an isomorphism of $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $\Bbb{R}^m$. It doesn't matter what dimensional space $M$ is embedded in. By definition, chart maps are diffeomorphisms.

Comment: @Nick Why not? $Df(x_0)$ being bijective and linear would be by definition an isomorphism. It seems I'm missing something quite fundamental here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54812/discussion-between-nick-and-simoes).